# OpenSUSE wired connection works but WiFi does not

Tags: wifi, opensuse, internet

I am able to connect to the Internet on OpenSUSE using a wired connect. I can connect to my wireless network and access Google but no other sites.

I'm not sure where to start. I've tried Googling but everything I am finding are forum posts from 5-6 years ago and I doubt they're relevant.

I have the OpenSUSE Tumbleweed installed. I have a Samsung laptop from approx 2014.

Here is my Wireless card info:

```
linux-dfyi:~ # hwinfo --wlan
13: PCI 100.0: 0282 WLAN controller                             
  [Created at pci.378]
  Unique ID: yWPJ.kQy5U_ZUp+C
  Parent ID: z8Q3.SQ434Dh94vE
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x088e "Centrino Advanced-N 6235"
  SubVendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x4060 "Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN"
  Revision: 0x24
  Driver: "iwlwifi"
  Driver Modules: "iwlwifi"
  Device File: wlp1s0
  Features: WLAN
  Memory Range: 0xf7c00000-0xf7c01fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 29 (no events)
  HW Address: fe:fb:db:90:37:00
  Permanent HW Address: c4:d9:87:09:0d:71
  Link detected: no
  WLAN channels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140
  WLAN frequencies: 2.412 2.417 2.422 2.427 2.432 2.437 2.442 2.447 2.452 2.457 2.462 2.467 2.472 5.18 5.2 5.22 5.24 5.26 5.28 5.3 5.32 5.5 5.52 5.54 5.56 5.58 5.6 5.62 5.64 5.66 5.68 5.7
  WLAN encryption modes: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP
  WLAN authentication modes: open sharedkey wpa-psk wpa-eap
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000088Esv00008086sd00004060bc02sc80i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: iwlwifi is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe iwlwifi"
  Config Status: cfg=no, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #9 (PCI bridge)
```

Tumbleweed Version:

```
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
# VERSION="20170729"
ID=opensuse
ID_LIKE="suse"
VERSION_ID="20170729"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20170729"
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm not sure where to start but ready to learn!

Comment: What happens if you try to ``ping`` or otherwise connect to a non-Google site?  Can you do a traceroute? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You are not connected to a wireless network.  (`Link detected: no`).  The 'Google' page is cached offline.

Try turning on the wireless hardware.  If there is a switch on your laptop, flip the switch.  When the wireless hardware is 'on', pick the wifi network and enter the password, using the system tray in the bottom right hand corner.

P.S.:  it is better practice to enter administrative commands from an unprivileged account using 'sudo'.